# C++ multiple inheritance preventing diamond

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Is there a way to define a class Foo in C++
so that

1. I can inherit from it
2. I can't "diamond inherit" from it

I.e.

```
class Cat: public Foo{} // okay
class Dog: public Foo{} // okay
class Weird: public Cat, public Dog {} // I want this to throw a compiler error
```

Comment: @vava: nice edit, didn't realize 1. 2. auto itemizes

Comment: You *don't* want to use virtual inheritance or you are unaware of it?

Comment: I was unaware of it. However, I'd also like to get a compiler error. The base class "Foo" i'm inheriting from is a invasive ref-counted pointer. I should not have two instances of it in an object.

Comment: You can always take ATL's approach and require the most derived class hold the refcount instead of the base.

Comment: Using private inheritance, there will only be a copy of the base `Foo`  type, so there would only be a reference count.

Comment: ATL's like virtual put the burden on the writer of the derivative class... I still find it better though, but it does not solve the problem that I don't know anyway to actually prevent the double-ref counting (at the level of `Foo`).

Answer (score 6):

Cprogramming.com Tutorial: Solving the Diamond Problem in C++ with ...

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html

Try This

For this type problem can be Avoid or solve by interface.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't realize there's "virtual" inheritance.

Comment: The problem is that `virtual` inheritance is on hand of those who derive, you can't really do anything to change that... so just hope those who write derivative classes read your comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another source of information:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html

Actually the whole C++ faq little it is really worth reading if you are programming on C++.